# Can't edit question - title already exists

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, title

I can't seem to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037697/program-received-signal-sigsegv-segmentation-fault):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/2vDNN6Q.png]

## Note: I was only editing the body of the question, not the title.

## Note2: The question was brand new.

Comment: The check on duplicate titles hasn't always been in place so it would have been possible at one point to create such duplicates/

Comment: @ChrisF The question is brand new.

Comment: @orlp - Oh. Unless the question was created via the Android or iOS app, and those don't have the duplicate title check enabled.

Comment: @ChrisF: The mobile apps weren't involved in this particular question. I don't know what happened here, but there are certainly plenty of duplicates out there. It seems like the right approach is to either close this question as a duplicate (and not bother editing) or fix the title to show what makes this particular question unique. (It looks like the OP tried to do just that in an edit.) Looking in the database, I don't see another question with the original title. Two old questions lack the final period however. Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: @JonEricson Perhaps when adding the question it checks the whole title (or more of it), when editing not so much of it?

Comment: @JonEricson Clicking on the link in the message comes to this, which doesn't have the full-stop/period: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5856628/1927206

Comment: @BillWoodger: My WAG is that when asking only exact matches are detected and when editing punctuation is stripped. But that's without looking at the code. Ideally both scenarios would use the same check.

Comment: It kind looks like `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.` could have been the title, and when the period was removed `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault` became a duplicate title. However, adding the period in for the screenshot did not remove the error dialog even though it would have brought the title back to its original state. The dialog will only be removed when the onchange event occurs which requires a blur from the input element. I was able to reproduce this http://i.imgur.com/KdKLCNN.png

Comment: @TravisJ I can get duplicate by ending with one, two, three etc full-stops/periods. With the full-stop(s)/period(s) you get the message, with the link I provided to a question with an identical title except for the full-stop/period. I think Jon's WAG will prove to be accurate in some way, shape, or form. The original title did have the full-stop/period (see revision history) and if you try to save with that title it gives the dupe message.

Comment: On the global meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191997/editing-a-post-gives-me-an-a-question-with-that-title-already-exists-error-par

Comment: Here's a similar question I asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109072/title-too-short-error-when-editing-a-question-without-modifying-the-title

Comment: I've proposed a potential improvement: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251264/improve-notice-user-receives-when-editing-a-question-with-a-dupe-title

Comment: Note, that title does suck... very hard.

Comment: It's now been edited, @Braiam. The result is much, much better.

Answer (score 29):

When this happens to me, I'm usually willing to edit the title, except when I don't know enough to edit the title to remove duplication.

I know enough about C++ to fix indentation and remove tags from the title. I used to program in C++. But that was over a decade ago. I may very well know enough about the language to correctly fix indentation and spelling errors, and yet not know enough about the context of the question to understand it well enough to propose a better title.

Please fix this feature to either:

1. Allow me to fix what I know how to fix, while not fixing the title (I don't like adding "#2" to the ends of titles)
2. Tell me when I start editing that you're going to force me to fix the title so I can avoid wasting my time on an edit you're not going to permit
3. Maybe fix the process so that the OP is the one who finds out about the duplicate title, and not a well-intentioned editor down the road.

Comment: Can we retag the OP to [feature-request]?

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to the comments on Shog9's answer, it's pretty well understood what's going on, so here's an answer with the information:

- When OP creates a question, it is *first* checked for uniqueness...
- ...and *then* [auto-corrected to fix some minor style problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100104/218334) (multiple `?`'s, for example).

  - Automated edits are approved automatically,
  - and don't create revision history, so...
- Future edits are treated as though they are editing the title; since the title is non-unique, they are rejected.

This is clearly a bug. The uniqueness check must check the title that will *actually be generated*, not pre-autocorrection title.

Comment: Yes, this is the main issue. Whether the editor is responsible for dupe titles is debateable. But the fact that the OP can bypass the dupe title check by simply adding two `??` is clearly a bug.

Comment: @slicedtoad Debateable? If this bug were fixed, questions could not be submitted with duplicate titles, so no, the editor would not be responsible for fixing them.

Comment: They would be if it was an old question. Or if they wanted to change the title to a duplicate (say, to fix a type-o). But, yes, it would be a far less frequent problem.

Comment: @slicedtoad True, it would still be an issue for old questions, but in the case of *changing* a title to *make* it a duplicate, **yes**, editors should be responsible for that!

Answer (score 7):

In theory, that question should never have been posted with that title in the first place. We strip trailing periods and there was already an existing question lacking said trailing period in the system.

However, what we didn't do at the time was trim trailing whitespace before attempting to remove or correct trailing punctuation. Trailing whitespace would then be subsequently removed just before posting, but it wasn't stripped out during validation. So, it looks like that question's original title had a few spaces at the end that allowed it to pass duplicate title checks in the first place.

A check for trailing whitespace was added to the validation code in October 2017... and I just pushed a change to move it to happen *before* trailing punctuation checks (whoops), so barring any other issues, we should be better at catching these issues before posts are created. I'm going to call this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for now, although for any existing questions in this situation, updating the title if/when the post is edited is the way to go.

Comment: _before_ or _after_ are neither perfect solutions, as demonstrated for you [by this edit to an existing title](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51518080/revisions). If we want a strict block, the regex should trim both spaces and punctuation at the same time, like: `([\s\.]*$)`

Answer (score -27):

There are multiple questions with this title already.

There are multiple questions with this title already *because we didn't always enforce unique titles.*

*This* question wasn't created with that title - it was normalized [via an automatic edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99871/can-should-we-get-rid-of-multiple-punctuation-marks/100104#100104). Because such edits don't create a revision history entry, this effectively means *any* further edits will be title edits.

We now enforce unique titles. If you're saving a question - whether editing or creating a new one - it *must* have a unique title. If it doesn't, then either vote to close it as a duplicate or edit the title to reflect *something* unique about the question.

Hint: segmentation faults nearly always happen because of *something else* wrong with the program. Figure out what the program is doing - for instance, dereferencing a pointer initialized to the return value of `rand()` - and make sure the title reflects *that*.

Clarification for LRiO: I'm not suggesting anyone answer questions via title edits. But if you're going to bother editing questions with terrible, nondescript titles, **please** try to understand what's being asked well enough to summarize it in the title - otherwise, you're just leaving more cruft to clutter up search results.

Comment: But as I have been told in the past editing the title to "Seg fault because programmer knows nothing about C" is not a valid title.

Comment: But _it's not my fault_ that the title is not unique! I should be able to edit the tags, or the body of this question without being held responsible for the duplicate title.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when did we start enforcing this policy?

Comment: _"Figure out what the program is doing"_ NO! No no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no no **no**. This is the OP's job, not ours.

Comment: At the _very_ least, it's the purview of answerers, not editors.

Comment: @David: Far too long ago.

Comment: I'm confused (not an uncommon state of affairs). That question was posted less than a day ago. I understand that long ago SO didn't enforce unique titles. But I'm pretty sure that policy went into effect more than a day ago. So the question remains: given that the OP of this question did not modify the title while trying to edit the other question, how is it that the title wound up as a duplicate of some other question's title?

Comment: -1, I apologize for my earlier rude comment, I'm just annoyed by being teached on basic stuff based on wrong assumptions. 1. I'm a 35k rep user with a gold C++ badge. I know how segmentation faults work, and how editing works. 2. It's not my question, I was just fixing indentation. It's not my responsibility to answer the question or fix other things about the question like the title. 3. The question was brand new, so a change of policy has nothing to do with it. All of that information was readily available to you when you answered this question, and to the people who upvoted it.

Comment: I agree with orlp.  I read his first question and immediately he is given one liners like he doesn't understand.  Even when he mentions that he does not EDIT the title people still give him "Nope you're wrong...", and I dont think question titles need to be unique, that is pretty scary.

Comment: Sorry, @orlp - I didn't recognize which bit was bothering you here - see my edit. For future reference, please try to describe the behavior you would *expect* to see when you intend a post here to be a bug report; if you just report a specific message like this, I'm going to assume you just don't understand what it means, since that's true in the vast majority of cases (yes, even for 35K users).

Comment: See my edit, @LightnessRacesinOrbit. All editing is "the OP's job". For everyone else, editing is optional.

Comment: See edit, @Peter: the title was modified by the system while the question was posted. I'm not overly-fond of how these automatic edits work either, but this *is* by-design.

Comment: @Shog9 If you remove all other cruft except that this question was created with a colliding title due to the stripping of multiple punctuation I'll change my downvote to an upvote. Even better would be to delete this answer and create a totally new one just containing that.

Comment: I'm not usually too stuck on edits fixing *every last problem* in a post, @John - but duplicate titles are a pretty serious error; if - as an editor - you're ignoring this, you're wasting your time and the time of anyone searching for that title in the future. I actually think we should be doing more to encourage title edits - awful lot of turd-polishing happening because editors overlook them.

Comment: I don't  care about downvotes, @orlp. This is my opinion on the situation; you're free to dislike or straight-up ignore the advice if you wish.

Comment: @Shog9 As soon as you force editors looking to improve a question in one aspect to improve it in multiple you will end up with editors not improving anything at all.

Comment: If the choice is between a smaller number of improved questions and a huge pile of generic titles, I'll err on the side of the former every time @orlp. I think this is a false dichotomy though; realistically, the dup-checker *usually* works well enough when asking to avoid this problem. I need to get around to adapting the smarter title blacklist we've been using on CodeReview for Stack Overflow - that would discourage a *lot* of the rest of lousy titles.

Comment: We are able to make multiple edits on a post so if someone can't think of a better title but can otherwise improve the post, forcing them to abandon their edit is silly to me: why not allow it, then let subsequent editors find a better title? It seems to me like you are punishing editors for the OP's mistake. It's great when editors can clean up a title, but banning them from making _any_ improvements when they can't? Dunno, biting the hand that feeds... SO is getting extremely prescriptive.

Comment: Yeah, the sky's been falling for 3+ years; a wonder we haven't all been crushed yet.

Comment: I guess the duplicate-title check when posting should come **after** the automatic-correction check when posting, not **before** it.

Comment: Something definitely doesn't smell right - if the title is going to be rejected by the system, that should happen when the OP saves it, not when someone else tries to edit it later. That way, we're forcing the author to engage with the site's policy, not letting them post a bad question and expecting someone else to clean up the mess. If it's working as described, you can use extra punctuation as a back-door to create as many duplicate titles as you want, which doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Do I understand this process correctly?  OP creates a question with a unique title, passes uniqueness test.  System autocorrects title to non-unique title, side-steps uniqueness test.  Editor attempts to edit body/tags (not title), but because autocorrection has since invalidated the title, title uniqueness fails and editor can't submit edits.  If this is the case, it would seem like a pretty clear bug with the autocorrection routine.

Comment: If I read the linked-to answer correctly, there should be no questions which end in a full-stop/period. The question in question, does end in a full-stop/period. So the linked-to answer doesn't seem to cover what happens when the question is automatically edited originally.

Comment: It sounds like we have all the facts necessary to understand what happened here - only we now need a separate answer that makes it clear what happened here.

Comment: @jedwards That's exactly what happened from what I can tell.

Comment: @remyabel This answer still doesn't address the issue directly. Nearly every sentence is irrelevant or obvious (e.g. titles must be unique - yup, that's what the error message says... :o). In particular, it tries to justify the way system works by explaining its internals, which is, again, irrelevant to its users. So, at least in my case, its not "mob mentality".