# Edit to an old question cannot be saved because title too long

Tags: bug, edits, title

I tried to edit an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/158778/3933332) and when I hit `Save Edits` it showed me this error, even though I didn't touch the title.
[image: error message "Title cannot be longer than 150 characters"]

Is there a new constraint, and if so, how can one possibly edit an old question without changing (shortening) its title?

Comment: I have encountered other checks, e.g. [on duplicate titles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists?rq=1), that kick in at edit submission time.

Comment: Yes, I saw that question/problem, which is even more weird

Comment: If we're meant to hold old posts to the same standards as new ones (a principal which I often see stated here on meta), then surely the right reaction is that the title *isn't* a good title, so an edit to the title should also happen?

Comment: Yes, yes. I see your point.

Comment: The title has been changed.

Comment: I was thinking there is no way the title needs to be that long.

Comment: More frustrating to me are questions with 'question' or 'problem' in the title.  I'm not clear how the OP gets that word into the question, but my impression is that it isn't just ancient questions that have this problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In the database the title is 250 characters, so somewhere back in the day the titles were longer. The limit is now 150.

That hurts when you edit an old question from before the limit was lowered. You have no other option than to edit the title, maybe salvaging relevant info by moving it in the body.

This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/363314)

```
select len(title) as [length of title]
, count(*) as [count]
from posts
where len(title)> 150
group by len(title)
order by 2
```

shows the number of question per specific title length.

Here is the *proof* that at least the SEDE schema has a posts table with  the length of column "Title" > 150:

> [image: sede posts.title nvarchar(250)]

Comment: There are 298 questions with title length > 150: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/363483/

Comment: That's tedious! It would be nice if, somehow, the editing process could take in account if the title was previously longer than 150 characters and allow it to still be longer than 150 characters in this case. And if the title is being reduced below the length, then the exception is lifted.

Comment: @JeromeJ at least on this site it is only a tiny fraction of the posts, and chances that these are going to be edited at some point are likely not very high. While it would be a useful feature to a few users in a very border kind of case, there are more important things. The costs outweigh the benefit I think. Also not a lot of other sites would benefit simply because they are too new to have those too long titles.

Comment: @simbabque I'm not sure if we can get any performance/storage improvement if we'd manage to get rid of all those lengthy title and set the row to `nvarchar (150)` instead. If so, this coukd be a mission.

Comment: @JeromeJ nvarchar is a dynamic width type in sql server so it really doesn't matter if the field is 250 or 150, it only matters if all those 20.000.000 would have used 250 chars. Reducing to 150 would matter in that case. For those ~300 questions the gain would be at max 60Kb  assuming they all took up the full 250 characters.

Comment: @rene That's true for SQL Server itself, but it's not necessarily true for whatever client library is used to access the data. Some libraries (at least classic ADO, though I'm guessing that's not the one that's used by SO) use fixed-size buffers in the returned result sets.

Comment: Shouldn't historical questions which fall foul of newer rules be marked as requiring review or some other attention... then we might find these issues are less common where a well-meaning editor is frustrated?

Comment: The only real benefit would be to remove a tiny bit of technical debt in the form of whatever check currently caps the title length to a value shorter than the DB field.  I doubt it'd be worth anyone from SE's time to do any work to facilitate the change.  If someone (or several someone's) were to go through all the old questions and edit them down the schema update might be worth throwing in as part of whatever their next major DB update is.  This'd probably need to be done SE wide, not just on SO though; and since the offenders are probably mostly/entirely dead, is still a debatable effort.

Comment: @Nateowami I just shorten about ~80 of those today, so I'm sure there are less than 160 long titles left now. But reducing the size of the column is not an option as we need to support long titles for deleted/undeleted questions, rollbacked questions, and history of previous revisions.

Comment: @Nateowami only one question left with a long title.