# Limiting the title length when asking a question

Tags: discussion

I notice a lot on Stack Overflow, some users ask their question just in the title and is quite long and does not place question on the editor.

**Question** Will Stack Overflow have a shorter limit on how long title should be?

In my opinion the title of the Question should be short and to the point on title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions with long titles should just be edited.
Setting an arbitrary (short) length limit doesn't really help anyone. Limitations like that are usually only put in place to prevent users from submitting ridiculous amounts of data where it shouldn't be. Length limits can't be used to force quality titles.

That said, there is already a length limit in place:

> *"Title cannot be longer than 150 characters."*

While 150 characters is still quite long, at least it prevents users from submitting novels.

Comment: Nice answer But I think that 150 characters, it to long.

Comment: I think 150 is fine. When a title is poorly worded, it can just be edited.

Comment: That is very true.

Comment: I think 150 can allow users to include error message, especially when error message is long

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305960 "Limit was once 250 before it was lowered to 150, there are some old questions left with such a long title. See query for the counts..."

Comment: @amuse: and quoting a full error message almost always makes a bad title. So actually I don't quite get your point, unless you meant to agree that 150 indeed is too long *because* it appears to invite posters to use such overly long titles.

Answer (score 3):

If a title describes the poster's issue accurately and completely, that is not a problem in itself. (Or if it is, then I want to have more of this problem.)

If the question *body* reads, in its entirety, "How can I do this? Please advice. Thank you very much." that *that's* where the problem is. Question body should stand on its own, without references to the title. Edit the question *body* until it does.

Comment: Not all 120 thousand questions found by [the very basic query `is:q body:"title"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+body%3A%22title%22) can be bad, can't they? ... Oh wait.