# Why was this user able to roll their question back to an edit with a 159 character long title

Tags: discussion, title, rollbacks, character-limit

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838831/ive-decoupled-my-user-model-from-the-main-domain-model-that-represents-a-perso) question with a title of 159 characters.  This is not surprising because the question was asked in May of 2009, before the [150 character limit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307558/limiting-the-title-length-when-asking-a-question) on titles was in place.

What is surprising is that a user reduced the question title to under 150 characters, and then the original poster was able to [rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/838831/revisions) to the long title in November 2017, after the 150 character limit was put in place.

Why was the title length limit not enforced on the rollback?

Comment: Rollbacks do not enforce anything: with a rollback you can make duplicate titles, titles with "question" or "problem", titles too long or too short, etc.

Comment: @Cœur: Or to put it another way: It's a bug. :-) But not one SE is likely to acknowledge as such, or fix.

Comment: maybe in 6 or 8 weeks...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem is probably not only the technical aspect of it, but just how are we supposed to handle the cases where a question can rollback the title because it has now (and didn't before) the same title than another ? Furthermore even if we do,one or two extra character will work around that.

Comment: @Walfrat you live with it? I'm sure nothing will explode when two questions just happen to get the exact same title through unconventional and uncommon circumstances :)

Comment: I don’t think it’s a bug. I actually wish most edits would work the same way (old question has “problem” in the title, you edit something unrelated, can’t save, decide not to improve anything).

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. If someone vandalises a question with a long title, it should be possible to roll it back

Comment: @Cœur It looks like the note in your profile about titles over 150 characters is now obsolete.

Comment: Youhou, thank you very much @MackM, that's a good job! I've updated my profile to deal with titles below 15 characters now. ;)

Comment: @MackM Your last fight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664205/is-the-performance-of-sql-server-cross-joins-with-conditionals-in-the-where-stat

Comment: @Cœur I saw that, but if the post owner wants it that way I'm not going to fight them.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A rollback is not interpreted as an edit that turns the post into what it was at an earlier point in time, requiring all of the validation that would be required to make such an edit.  A rollback turns the post into what it was at that point in time, no questions asked.

Comment: Sounds correct to me. The question was validated when accepted the first time. Versioning manages the version; validation manages how a question (version) comes to be.

Comment: There are small visual exceptions, @Servy, as a rollback doesn't affect the list of displayed Duplicates, as demonstrated by [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48968560/revisions).