# Unable to edit an old question because the existing title is not good enough

Tags: bug

Refer to this question ["Where is my GAC located"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19980650/3834)?

I just want to edit the formatting (eg:put a code sample quote around relevant strings) and I don't want to edit the title. But SO just doesn't allow me because

> Title cannot contain "Where is my GAC located?".
>
> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance,
>   see: How do I ask a good question?

I can understand where this error message is coming from, but is it possible to relax this restriction for old question edit?

Comment: Probably a more productive approach would be to unlock the privilege to use "forbidden" language in question titles at a particular rep level, perhaps additionally behind earning a specific badge. Related meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/let-users-with-sufficient-reputation-use-problem-in-titles

Comment: On a related note, I think it's the word "my" triggering the regex. Changing it to "the" should push the title through.

Comment: @tripleee we can ask shog9 to... oh wait, I guess it will stay like that for the next six years at least.

Comment: better dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288001/cant-edit-question-title-already-exists